# Internet started working in VirtualBox Fedora but was not working on Ubuntu

Tags: virtualbox, fedora, modem, mts

I am using MTS MBlaze USB modem. I have a dual-boot option of Win 7 and Ubuntu. Ubuntu didn't recognize the USB device and the debian driver that came with modem, failed to run on Ubuntu.

When I setup VirtualBox with Fedora, suddenly internet started. Is it that the device is still connected via Win 7, or Fedora is recognizing the device?

Shall I install Fedora in a separate partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VirtualBox uses Windows' internet connection and only virtualizes network interface.

If your USB modem doesn't work with Ubuntu, it is very likely that it won't work with Fedora either.

Comment: Actually the debian driver provider by the ISB was of the older version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo apt-get install ndiswrapper`

ndiswrapper is a tools for installing windows driver on linux. u must "steal" file with .inf and .sys extension on windows (if you know about the dir where the driver is installed).

or, your modem have a partition with isofs filesystem. it make the modem have 2 port to be known as USB. linux can't read the second, but can read the first. try usb-modeswitch to fix the problem if your modem type like that.
(^_^)v